# How to Display a Formula Value in the Format '.../...'?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, progress, progress-bar

I am currently working on a progress bar. Above or next to the progress bar I would like to display the value of progress made not as a percentage but rather in a format like this:

5/4

This shall illustrate that 4 out of 5 tasks have already been completed.

Since the total number of tasks as well as the number of completed tasks shall be obtained from another sheet with the help of a formula, I am desperately looking for a formula which could perform this kind of job.

Any help would be appreciated a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing now :S... Why do you tagged it as [progress] and [progress-bar] if it's about formulas? You can use something like: `A1 & "/" & A2`?

Comment: =COUNTIF('Worksheet A'!A1:A10,"Category A")&"/"&COUNTIFS('Worksheet A'!A1:A10,"Category A",'Worksheet A'!B1:B10,"Done")

Comment: Just an observation: the universal convention for 4 out of 5 completed is 4/5 rather than 5/4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `& "/" &` in place of `"/"`.
Eg : Formula of a cell `=B4& "/" &C4` would display `<value at B4>/<value at C4>`

Comment: Thanks! So would this statement work then? =COUNTIF('Worksheet A'!A1:A10,"Category A")&"/"&COUNTIFS('Worksheet A'!A1:A10,"Category A",'Worksheet A'!B1:B10,"Done")

Comment: Yes. It will give you outputs like `0/0` or `1/0` etc.

Comment: Is it then possible to do some conditional formatting based on these values?

Comment: Yes, [Conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

Comment: But what format would I have to choose for the cell value? Percentage or something else?

Comment: Select the fractions, set its format to be fraction and goto Cond. formatting and choose "new rule" then set a formatting rule.